# Binding Em.Select selection value to object from store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember.select

I can't figure out how to use the valueBinding property of Ember.Select to bind the selected value directly to a object from Ember.Data's store.

Fiddle: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jipamiro/14/edit

The problem I'm facing is that the model returns DS.RecordArray object and I just need the selection value. I tried "firstObject", computed properties and so on to no avail and running out of ideas....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here is a working bin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jipamiro/16/edit)

I modified the model hook in the route and the valueBinding property in the template. In the model hook, I am specifying which item to find instead of returning the whole array.

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('setup', 0); 
  } 
});

{{view Ember.Select class="form-control" 
  viewName="channel"
  content=channelOptions
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  valueBinding="selectedChannel"}}
```

Comment: Doh! Thanks, seems I missed some obvious things here :)